# HELP - removing JDBC boilerplate code with java 7 and up

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

[Online examples](http://www.journaldev.com/2483/jdbc-transaction-management-and-savepoint-example-tutorial) of JDBC exhibit fair amount of code-clutter, compared to RAII/C++ or Python DB. Don't we all want something less verbose? :) So, in the spirit of trimming things a little, is the following code snippet the most minimal yet correct take on JDBC (MySQL Connector/J) under Java 7 with autocommits off?

```
try ( Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection() ) {
  PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(..);
  stmt.setInt(1, ..);
  stmt.executeUpdate();
  con.commit();
}
```

Note, no *finally-block* with explicit "checks and rollbacks".

Answer (score 1):

Of course you must import the relevant packages. Then you **have** to use `Class.forName(DB_DRIVER_CLASS);`. Finally, you can omit the `catch` part (with the closure of the connection), but only if you terminate immediately the program, without performing other connections or other database operations.

Comment: "only if you terminate immediately" -- why would you say so? What sort of resource leaks in above code snippet that requires program termination?

Comment: Because each connection, until it is open, "subtracts" resources both to the DBMS Server (in terms of resources used for the connection and of the number of other connections that can be accepted) and to the client (in terms of resources used by the java program). Moreover, if for some reason the `autoconnection` is set to false, the current transaction remains unterminated, reducing the degree of concurrency over the data accessed.

Comment: That's what try-with-resources does. It releases the connection when the scope exits, with exception or gracefully.